# NestJS Http Module

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, nestjs

I took this example from the nestJS docs (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module#http-module), which is a minimal example of my problem:

```
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  findAll(): Observable<AxiosResponse<Cat[]>> {
    return this.httpService.get('http://localhost:3000/cats');
  }
}
```

How can I extract the actual Array of Cats from the Observable<AxiosResponse<Cat[]>>?
I tried the following but it gives me a subscriper object which I also don't know how to unwrap to get the actual data.

```
const cats = await this.catsService.findAll().subscribe((val) => val);
```

Comment: try `await this.catsService.findAll().toPromise();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    return this.httpService.get('http://localhost:3000/cats').toPromise();
  }
```

}

```
const cats = await this.catsService.findAll().data
```

worked for me.

Comment: using `toPromise` is deprecated now 

check this : https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Answer (score 8):

Using `.toPromise()` is deprecated now check this : https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Listing below is an example using the new approach

**UPDATE Oct 2021**

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

.
.
.

const observable = await this.httpService.get('url').pipe(map((res) => res.data));

// you can use the data object now !!
const data = await lastValueFrom(observable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
  findAll(): Observable<Cat[]> {
    return this.httpService.get('http://localhost:3000/cats')
      .pipe(map(response => response.data);
  }
```

Comment: I get an error with message `cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?`.